# Calculating ranks from the following data

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I calculate the rank for all `"type 10"` rows in the data below using just sql?

The sql will go into a stored procedure, with no other scripting involved.

The `parent` holds the `total` of all rows in column `total`, and the `total votes` in `votes`.

I update the `perCent` col using this, so this should give you an idea. Maybe calculate ranks along with this?

All rows are linked by parent -> child relationship.

All is based on total votes and total candidates. Candidates are type `10`

```
UPDATE likesd p
        JOIN likesd h
        ON p.parent = h.id
        AND p.country = h.country
    SET p.percent = TRUNCATE(100*p.votes/h.votes,2);
```

**Raw Data**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"   "total" "rank"
"24"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "30"    "0"         ""      "0"
"25"    "3"     "24"        "US"        "30"    "0"         "3"     "0"
"26"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "15"    "50.00"     ""      "0"
"27"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "5"     "16.66"     ""      "0"
"28"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"     ""      "0"
```

**Desired results**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"   "total" "rank"
"24"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "30"    "0"         ""      "0"
"25"    "3"     "24"        "US"        "30"    "0"         "3"     "0"
"26"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "15"    "50.00"     ""      "1" // Rank 1. Has 15 votes out of 30 (see parent row above)
"27"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "5"     "16.66"     ""      "3" // And so on.
"28"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"     ""      "2"
```

Comment: You should be able to use the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function/3333697#3333697), except you use `IF(type = 10, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, 0) as Rank`

Comment: @barmar I'm close. If you read this could you help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015937/incorporating-a-ranking-system-into-this-sql I'm a little stuck with adding the `@` part in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,type,parent,country,votes,perCent,total, FIND_IN_SET( votes, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( votes
ORDER BY votes DESC ) 
FROM table WHERE type=10 )
) AS rank
FROM table
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b108/6)

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3510f9/1)

```
UPDATE scores SET rank= (FIND_IN_SET(votes, (
SELECT * FROM(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( votes
ORDER BY votes DESC ) 
FROM scores WHERE type=10)x ) ) )
```

Comment: Works very nicely. I was hoping I'd be able to do it like in the update statement in my question, where all the children update their parents in one go, because this actually is an update.