# Incorporating an incrementing value into this sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do something like the first answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function/3333697) Adding the `@part` which outputs a rank, somehow I'm not able to get it right.

The sql I'm using is:

```
select child.id, child.perCent
from likesd parent
join likesd child
   on parent.id = child.parent
where parent.type = 3
order by parent.id, child.perCent desc;
```

I some how cannot fit the `@` parts inside the above sql, and need help there.

```
SELECT    first_name, // This sql is from the previous question
          age,
          gender,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      person p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  age;
```

So:

```
select child.id, child.perCent, @curRank := @curRank + AS rank
    from likesd parent, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    join likesd child
       on parent.id = child.parent
    where parent.type = 3
    order by parent.id, child.perCent desc;
```

In the end, what I'm trying to achieve is in the Desired results. Can you see how I can do this?

**Main Table**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent"
"24"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "30"    "0"
"25"    "3"     "24"        "US"        "30"    "0"
"26"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "15"    "50.00"
"27"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"
"28"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "5"     "16.66"

"29"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "50"    "0"
"30"    "3"     "29"        "US"        "50"    "0"
"31"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "20"    "40.00"
"32"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "15"    "25.00"
"33"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "15"    "35.00"
```

**Expected results:**

```
"id"    "perCent" "rank" // Rank is calculated based on the sql order above
"26"    "50.00"   "1" 
"27"    "33.33"   "2"
"28"    "16.66"   "3"

"31"    "40.00"    "1" // New parent, new ranking
"33"    "35.00"    "2"
"32"    "25.00"    "3"
```

Comment: Why do you expect 31, 32, and 33 in the result? They have parent = 29, whose type is 1, not 3.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, my bad. I made edits to the data. Posting all of it wold make things difficult for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, perCent, 
       @curRank := if(parent = @prevParent, @curRank + 1, 1) AS rank,
       @prevParent := parent
from (
    select child.id, child.perCent, child.parent
    from likesd parent
    join likesd child
       on parent.id = child.parent
    where parent.type = 3
    order by parent.id, child.perCent desc) x
cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevParent := null) r
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b2c8/1)

Comment: :-) This gives a continuous ranking. Just like what I achieved.  The idea is to start with 1 for each parent children (like in desired results). I've corrected the question where 31,32,33 had wrong parents.

Comment: Updated the answer to do per-parent ranking.

Comment: Thanks, Barry. I can see this wouldn't have been possible with basic sql.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select child.id, 
       child.perCent, 
       CASE parent.id 
      WHEN @curParent THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1 
      ELSE @curRank := 1 AND @curParent := parent.id  END as Rank
from  likesd parent, likesd child, (SELECT  @curParent := 0, @curRank := 0) r
where parent.id = child.parent
and   parent.type = 3
order by parent.id, child.perCent desc;
```

Comment: There's an error at AS rank in your sql, that I cant get across since the past 10 minutes. Any idea?

Comment: Works just like the way I did. But that's not the idea. See the desired results. The rank needs to reset for each parent. That's where I got stuck too.

Comment: Works well. Just one small question, you've deviated from my original sql. Your sql and mine will output the same result, right? There wont be problems...

Comment: Yes, I have used your query to do it, just changed join condition